# Mod_Rewrite hiding directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having little issue with mod_rewrite rule. The rule seem to be working but blocks access to the directory and its files.

Here is what i want to accomplish

```
www.example.com/about-us/  *** Parent rule

www.example.com/about-us/our-mission.html *** child rule
```

Although, my rule is accomplishing this but blocking access to the physical file and directory on the server.

On the same server i have admin interface where user need to access to make changes...

```
www.example.com/manage/dash.php
```

When i attempt to access the directory /manage or its is files, i am redirected to 404 page that is a redirected  generated by the child rewrite rule.

When i comment out the child rewrite rule i am able to access these mentioned but with child rule, access is blocked.

Please see my rewrite code below and help me identify the issue.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


 #This rule will rewrite url to the main page www.example.com/about-us
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?get_parent=$1 [L]

#This rule  will rewrite url to the secondary url www.example.com/abou-us/our-mission.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?get_parent=$1&get_child=$2 [L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to exclude files/dirs from 2nd RewriteRule as well.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This rule will rewrite url to the main page www.example.com/about-us
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?get_parent=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This rule  will rewrite url to the secondary url www.example.com/abou-us/our-mission.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?get_parent=$1&get_child=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I see, so this did resolve the issue, the first set of exclusion are eliminated once the rule is ended. Haven't thought of of this way.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty fair, as your url www.example.com/manage/dash.php is matching the regexp. With the [L] at the end of the first rule, the 2 conditions are not used anymore for the second rule

You should add a non matching pattern too (see [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Here we supposed that the file /manage/dash.php really exists.

Hope it will help you.